# Tried to calculate the adjoint of the integral operator in two different ways and found two different results

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $I:L^2([0,1])\to L^2([0,1])$ be the following operator
$$I(f)(x)=\int_{[0,x]}f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t.$$
I want to find the adjoint of $I$. I tried to do that in two ways. The first was trying to find $I^*$ such that $\langle If,g\rangle=\langle f,I^* g\rangle$. Using that I found
$$I^*(f)(x)=\int_{[x,1]}f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t.$$

However, I know that $I$ is a kernel operator with $K(x,t)=\chi_{[0,x]}.$ I also know that the adjoint of a kernel operator is also a kernel with $\overline{K(t,x)}$ as kernel. This implies
$$I^*(f)(x)=\int_{[0,1]}\chi_{[0,t]}\:f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t=\int_{[0,1]}\:f(t)\:\mathrm{d}t.$$

What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic function you have as your kernel is missing an argument which is I think where it went wrong. Your kernel should be $K(x,t) = \chi_{[0,x]}(t)$, so that your adjoint kernel is given by $\chi_{[0,t]}(x)$. The constructed adjoint operator is then

$$I^*(f)(x) = \int_0^1 \chi_{[0,t]}(x)f(t)dt$$

But now note that what this really means is that we're integrating $t$ from where $x$ is and the characteristic turns on, up until $1$. But that's the same thing as

$$\int_x^1 f(t) dt.$$